# PDFTK, PHP, and Filling forms out

Tags: php, pdf, pdftk

I have a PDF file that I've created a webpage form for, basically a bunch of inputs just to fill in the contents of the PDF file. I've managed to fill in text with ease.. Although checkboxes aren't really working. I've tried two different things.. One was this:

```
<</T(CheckBoxName)/V(Yes)>>
```

number two was this:

```
<</T(CheckBoxName)/V /Yes>>
```

Neither work. Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Yes. You failed to read all nice articles in help center and did not add enough relevant code.

Comment: What help center? Also, as far as the code goes, I have the code working for things that are strings... and <</T(CheckBoxName)/V(Yes)>> goes inside a string of mine that works for text things. Makes sense?

Comment: [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how your field is formatted first with the command:

```
pdftk yourFile.pdf dump_data_fields
```

For checkboxes, you should get something like:

```
FieldType: Button
FieldName: CheckBoxName
FieldFlags: 49152
FieldValue: CheckBoxName1
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Off
FieldStateOption: choice1
FieldStateOption: choice2
FieldStateOption: choice3
FieldStateOption: choice4
FieldStateOption: choice5
```

So your first writing was the good one (if you want to check the first option):

```
<</T(CheckBoxName)/V(choice1)>>
```